# Apply a pose to a 3D model/mesh

Tags: 3d, mesh, animation, model

Assuming that I have pose information for a human, is there any ways/tools to apply that pose to a 3D model?

Basically, given continous pose information say from a dancing person, I like to animate a 3D model with that pose, so performing exactly the same dance.

e.g. here the left pose is applied to a model to become right:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use it on the bones of the model.

Comment: How can I do that? Samples/tools/free API.

Comment: I don't know about APIs, I usually code such things manually. But there certainly should be animation packages out there.

Comment: Wow is it that easy to do via code?! If you got anything, please share it.

Comment: You can find tutorials on it: https://veeenu.github.io/2014/05/09/implementing-skeletal-animation.html